# Modifying Hadoop Terasort Example

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hadoop2

I have modified the hadoop terasort example located at the following path:

`hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/TeraSort.java`

in https://github.com/apache/hadoop.

Then, from the root directory, after running `mvn clean install -DskipTests`, the jar located at `hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/target/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` does not seem to be updated with my edits.

Is this the correct approach to rebuilding the hadoop examples after modifying the src of one of the examples?